# jQuery - anchor click

Tags: jquery

I've got a working a.click() function in jquery...
But if I click an anchor, I open an new window... But how can I stop the browser from opening a new window itself??

example:

```
    $('a').each(function() {
            $(this).click(function(e) {
                if($(this).attr('target') == '_popup') {
                    //here is code to open window (already exists)

                    //try to stop propagation, but doesn't work...
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }

                hideNSL();
            });
    });
```

so, how do I stop the event??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
e.preventDefault()
```

but here `return false` may also do it which is in the other answer. `preventDefault` can be used in more senarios and is a more generic "stop the default event action", see: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: this worked (put I can't accept your answer... I have to wait -.-)

Answer (score 4):

Add this to the end of your click event:

```
return false;
```

So for example:

```
$('a').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(e) {
            var toReturn = true;
            if($(this).attr('target') == '_popup') {
                //here is code to open window (already exists)

                toReturn = false;
            }

            hideNSL();
            return toReturn;
        });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT, I stand corrected .preventDefault is not a jQuery function.

Comment: Since it wasn't clarified in the question this still might be handy for other users stumbeling on the question don't you think?